# How can I change color of top & bottom bar in Android Options Menu?

Tags: android, menu, optionmenu

Options menu bars

[image: 1]

I have tried everything to try and change or remove them bars. It doesn't go away.

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sequel100black45</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/my_grey</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_grey</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/my_grey_variant</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>

        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">0.5dp</item>
    </style>
```

options.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/search_item"
        android:title="Search" />
    <item android:id="@+id/upload_item"
        android:title="Upload" />
    <item android:id="@+id/copy_item"
        android:title="Copy" />
    <item android:id="@+id/print_item"
        android:title="Print" />
    <item android:id="@+id/share_item"
        android:title="Share" />
    <item android:id="@+id/bookmark_item"
        android:title="BookMark" />


</menu>
```

Activity

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options, menu);


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I have tried to change the colors of popup backgrounds in the styles sheet but it just doesn't remove them bars.